# how to handle sub view orientation?

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, badge

I am trying to add a sub view via Code.

```
MKNumberBadgeView *numberBadge = [[MKNumberBadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, -51, 40, 40)];
    numberBadge.value = 5;

self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.zPosition = -1;
[self.view addSubview:numberBadge];
```

Now when i rotate my device how it doesn't move from its location  i want it to be orientation (Landscape as well as Portrait) friendly 
I am an creating application for iphone4/5 which supports both orientation .
basically i am trying to add a badge to a button so found this class reference MKNumberBadgeView .

Kindly suggest how to handle subview .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: i want it to be location friendly I am an????? what you want.. edit again and be specific.

Answer (score 0):

use MKNumberBadgeView by xib :-

in .xib file
take a view then set its class name 'MKNumberBadgeView' add to button in xib.

in .h file
@property (retain) IBOutlet MKNumberBadgeView* badgeOne; then set IBOutlet to view.

it is  orientation (Landscape as well as Portrait) friendly